# Jquery - APPEND is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, append

I am looking to find the html in first header in the page and add some html to it. Seems pretty simple but it is not working. I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

```
var str = $('h1:first').html();
$('h1:first').html(str.append("(<a class="dialogM" href="/alerts/alert1.html" title="Medical"><img src="/images/alert1.gif"></a>)"));
```

The error it is giving is - "TypeError: str.append is not a function"

Comment: Are the parentheses inside the string intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.append()` is a jQuery function that works on jQuery objects. You are passing a string `str` to it which won't work. Try:

```
$('h1:first').append('<a class="dialogM" href="/alerts/alert1.html" title="Medical"><img src="/images/alert1.gif"></a>');
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k1d7vscz/)**

Comment: Your wording is off, and you seem to like modifying the contents of strings. `.append()` can take a string as a parameter just fine.

Comment: @4castle My *wording* is off?

Comment: "You are passing a string to it which won't work" but then you proceed to pass a string to it.

Comment: @4castle - That refers to the OP's use of `str.append(...`

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a string. Strings don't have an `append` method; they concatenate with `+`.

What you probably meant to do was:

```
$('h1:first').html(str + '(<a class="dialogM" href="/alerts/alert1.html" title="Medical"><img src="/images/alert1.gif"></a>)');
```

or even better:

```
$('h1:first').append('(<a class="dialogM" href="/alerts/alert1.html" title="Medical"><img src="/images/alert1.gif"></a>)');
```

Comment: No assumption. The quotes are wrong. Test out your code.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks, I see it now.